# Can and did the Q ever give their powers to mortal beings (aside from Riker)?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q

In an episode of TNG, Q gave Riker God-like powers. Aside from this incident, did the Q ever give/lend their powers to mortal beings? If one receives the powers, would he be considered a Q?

Comment: You answered your question with the first sentence. I don't see anything that remains to be answered.

Comment: I meant aside from Riker!

Comment: "Did the Q give their powers to anyone, except for the time that they did?"

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by the "can" in your title. You're asking if it's possible for the Q to lend their power to a mortal being? What sort of proof are you looking for?

Comment: You're really asking two questions here: 1) Can/Have the Q lent/given their powers to a mortal and 2) Would that make them a Q?  If your focus is on the first question, then I will close it because you answer it in your own question with Riker.  If you want to edit it to focus more on the second part of the question about whether such a being would be considered a Q based on the evidence we have (and this is addressed in both the answers below), then I see no problem with it.

Answer (score 7):

Technically in [TNG: Deja Q](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deja_Q_(episode)), Q starts off as a mortal human.  He was stripped of his powers and given a choice to be turned into anything, so he chose human.

Now, I realize that Q wasn't *born* human, and that he *used to be* a Q, and--setting aside questions about the "reality" of a Q's actions and creations--the following does fit within the confines of your question as asked: **when the Q continuum made Q (the mortal) a Q (albeit again), they granted powers to a mortal.**

I know this is not the example you are looking for.  But the mortal-Q was truly just a human.  Then he was a Q (again).

Comment: You have my +1 for being [technically correct](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo)

Comment: as soon as I saw the question, this was the answer that occurred to me as well.  +1 also

Comment: @Valorum - Ha!  I love that quote and use it all the time!

Answer (score 6):

They can, and they did. In the episode [*Hide and Q*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Hide_and_Q_%28episode%29) Q bestows Riker with Q powers. Aside from Riker there are no canon (i.e. TV or movie) examples of a mortal being given the Q power, although it is possible to be born with them.

As to that mortal then being considered Q, anyone with the Q powers is Q (the Continuum considered [Amanda Rogers](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Amanda_Rogers) to be Q, even though she was born and raised as a human). But it is possible to give up the powers (or have them taken away) and thus become a mortal (again).

Comment: That's the first sentence in my question !!!!

Comment: Indeed. Your question answered itself.

Comment: I meant aside from Riker. Question edited

Comment: In addition to *Amanda Rogers* there is also *Junior*.

Comment: @bitmask I didn't count Junior because he wasn't born or raised as a human (presumably).

Comment: I believe Amanda Rogers, while raised human, was born Q.  Memory Alpha says she was born to Q parents who were in human form - not sure how you want to call that one, really.

Comment: If you want to add citations of Q being stripped of their powers, there's: [Q](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Q#Human), [Quinn](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Quinn), and [Junior](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Q_%28Junior%29).

Comment: @Iszi True, Amanda was Q all the time. But she was born as a human would be, and raised as a human would be. Culturally she identified with humanity more than the Continuum (if she were asked in a census which group she identified the most with, I'd wager she would check Human over Q).

Comment: Wouldn't you need to actually be in the Continuum or ov that species to be considered Q?  The Enterprise has encountered other species with reality warping abilities that weren't considered Q.

Comment: @Monty129 Before Junior there apparently had never been a Q made/born before (Amanda was conveniently forgotten), but whether the Q have inducted other mortal races to grow the continuum is never stated, to my knowledge. As far as I know Riker is the only mortal offered the chance to be Q, and he turned it down. So what makes a Q, Q is up for interpretation.

Comment: @Xantec: But he had a human auntie :)

Answer (score 4):

Arguably the Q, in allowing the crew of the Voyager to enter the Q Continuum  and operate Q weaponry in [VOY: The Q and the Grey](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/306.htm) shared some of their powers.

> **FEMALE Q:** *Q and I have a plan to end the war. Call off your troops.*
>
> **JANEWAY:** *Do as she says and I'll call my people off.*
>
> **FEMALE Q:** *They may be humanoids, but **they're using our weapons**.*
>
> **COLONEL Q:** *Cease fire! Cease fire!*

Comment: It was a horrible plot device in that episode, but it definitely answers the question.

Comment: I don't think this one is the Q giving *all* their powers, they just gave the Voyager crew access to their weapons. To humans the battle looked like the American Civil War, a clear sign they did not have Q powers.

Comment: @Hans - You'll note that I started the answer with "arguably" since it's not really clear to what extent the crew understood what was going on or why their involvement was more effective than simply creating a bunch of automatons to wave the guns around.

Comment: @Valorum You're right, I should have read your answer more carefully. In the end you also say "some of their powers" which is of course true. Q weapons would be nothing like tangible weapons normally used and therefore their usage would rely on "being Q". I accept your argument. :-)